# In an OO language, what do you name your class that contains the Main method?

Tags: c#, oop, naming-conventions

For instance in C# or Java, you always have a main() method used to get your program running. What do you name the class that it is in? Some ideas I would use would just be "Program" or the name of the program itself. What would be considered conventional in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Studio creates "Program.cs" these days, which seems pretty reasonable. Another self-documenting name I rather like is "EntryPoint".

Comment: Oooh, I like "EntryPoint". "Program" just seems ambiguous to me, outside of knowing that Visual Studio uses the name by default.

Comment: I like EntryPoint -- very clear

Comment: Yup EntryPoint was what I always used in the days before Visual Studio started defaulting to Program. Still prefer EntryPoint though.

Comment: +1 for Program.cs - keep it default for the sake of people that have to maintain your code later.

Comment: @Kev: I'm afraid your comment still leaves me none the wiser as to why my answer apparently deserves a downvote. For being obvious? I don't see that as a barrier to "goodness". Ah well.

Comment: @Jon - Sorry Jon...I should have a big yellow sticky on the PC reminding me that Stackoverflow and a bottle and a half of Chilean red don't mix. I'm sure I had a point but it got lost in the mists of inebriation at 2am.

Comment: @Kev: Not to worry. If you think of it again, please add it :)

Answer (score 4):

I use either Main or Main

Comment: But not Main, right?

Answer (score 2):

"Launcher"

Answer (score 1):

I name the main class after the application itself.  E.g. a Calculator program might have a "CalculatorProgram" or just a "Calculator" class.

Considering that VS names your main class whatever you name your application, I think this is pretty standard.

Comment: It actually automatically names it 'Program' if it's a console appy.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C Cocoa, main() is the C function itself. It sends a message to the *NSApplication* object which represents the running application.

Comment: Can you explain some more for us folks that aren't familiar with Obj-C Cocoa? Are you saying there is not an initial class that is used?

Comment: @d03boy: Bingo. Same for C++. Not all OO languages are as obsessive about forcing everything into object classes as Java/C# (and C# is becoming less so).

Comment: Obj-C is a superset of C. Everything which is OK in C is also OK in Obj-C, including the way main() is used.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer ConsoleStub.cs for console applications and Core.cs for other

Comment: I usually call it Core too. I also give my classes abstract names, though, that have nothing to do with its actual function (unless necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Program seems to be the standard. Works for me :D

Answer (score 1):

Main. The package where it is placed says the rest.

```
com.finance.calculator.Main
```

And in the Main I only have:

```
public static void main( String [] args ) { 
    FinanceCalculator calc = new FinanceCalculator();
    calc.show(); // or start(); or init. or whatever.
}
```

:S  I hope I never have to code a Finance Calculator :S :S

Comment: I think that would not work in C#, since a static method Main in class Main would be the static constructor :)

Comment: @OregonGost. Really? Is there a difference between "main" and "Main" in C#? additionally, what is an static constructor ? :P

Answer (score 1):

I've always used FooLauncher, because it allows me to encapsulate all the logic about command-line parsing in one class (rather than trying to get it into one method), which also allows better testability. It's also better segregation of concerns: Foo might be something that you use outside the command line, but FooLauncher is there to launch Foo given command-line processing.

This is particularly important in an application that overall has multiple command-line tools available: each one has its own Launcher. Just saying Program makes little sense if your "program" has multiple command-line tools.

Answer (score 0):

*XApplication*, where X is a descriptive name of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think use the default name of the language would be a good idea...others will know that there is the main()

Answer (score 0):

I think Program is a conventional case.  In my case, I'm more somehow bothered to think about the name I should give to namespace especially if it contains only one class.  In absence of definitive guidelines for naming of namespace with only one class, I come up with a pattern like this:  Stub for abstract classes, Impl for implementation, Project for the name of compiled dll/exe.

example:

FootwearRemotingStubProject.dll:

```
namespace FootwearRemotingStubProject
{
    public class FootwearRemotingStub
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

FootwearRemotingImplProject.exe:

```
using FootwearRemotingStubProject;

namespace FootwearRemotingImplProject
{
    public class FootwearRemotingImpl: FootwearRemotingStub
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me, but FootwearRemotingStubProject does not sound very descriptive to me even though it has a lot of words. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I somehow concur, it's just an interim approach for me to name Remoting code-partners(DLL + EXE[runs on Mono]).  Also, it helps me not to think too hard how to name my class differently from the namespace that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

I like "StartUp"

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET:

`Public Module Main

   Public Sub Main(String args())

   End Sub

 End Module`

Answer (score 0):

I don't put it in a class. In fact, I don't even use a method, just a snippet of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts 'Look Ma, no class, no method!'
```

Comment: Whoever voted this down is wrong. Execute this one-line ruby script: `raise 'snafu'`. You'll see `foo.rb:1:in \`<main>': snafu (RuntimeError)`. The code is already wrapped in a "main" method...

Comment: @smotchkiss: Actually, `main` is an *object*, not a method. It's the anonymous global object that all code that is not inside a class, module or method is executed in.